# How can I specify certificate authority when creating a model in Sagemaker with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ssl-certificate, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

We try to create a model in Sagemaker with boto3 based on an image we saved in a private artifactory. We found a way to setup the basic credentials acording to the doc https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-containers-inference-private.html but I cant find a solution to pass the certificate authority.

The code we use to create the model is

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('sagemaker')

response = client.create_model(
    ModelName='model-name',
    PrimaryContainer={
        'Image': 'local-repo.my_artifactory_endpoint/train:latest',
        'ImageConfig': {
            'RepositoryAccessMode': 'Vpc',
            
        },
        'Environment': {
            'SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM': 'train.py',
            "SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY": "/opt/ml/model/code",
            "SAGEMAKER_CONTAINER_LOG_LEVEL": "20",
            "SAGEMAKER_REGION": <my-region>,
            "MMS_DEFAULT_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT": "500"
        }
    },
    ExecutionRoleArn=<my-role>,
    VpcConfig={
        'SecurityGroupIds': [
            ...
        ],
        'Subnets': [
            ...
        ]
    },
    EnableNetworkIsolation=False
)
```

After, when we try to create an endpoint based on that model we endup with ther error:

```
Attempt to pull model image local-repo.my_artifactory_endpoint/train:latest failed due to error constructing client to call registry: constructing authentication challenge manager: Get "https://local-repo.my_artifactory_endpoint/v2/": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.
```

We don't find a way to pass this certificate or to ignore ssl option.

Comment: Is the registry in the same VPC as the SageMaker instance? If not, I am not sure this will work. More info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_ContainerDefinition.html#sagemaker-Type-ContainerDefinition-Image.

Comment: It is not in the same VPC but it is accesible from my VPC. I can access with a simple docker login from an EC2 instance for example

Comment: The EC2 instance used by SageMaker?

Comment: Yes, exactly, with proper docker config there is no prob in Sagemaker instances

Comment: Are you able to register your model into ECR?

Comment: Nope, the service is blocked by the administrator of the account.

Comment: When you stated you can access the repo from EC2 was this EC2 instance launched in the same Subnet as the Endpoint?

Comment: Yes, exactly, they are both in the same subnet.